# same partition scheduled multiple times for check on next boot

Tags: 18.04, disk-check

This is how I am currently greeted after login:

```
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sdb2 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda6 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

Alright, every now and then, the disks need to be checked. But what confuses me is that the same partition `/dev/sda1` occurs in this list a dozen times. Is this normal?

---

**EDIT:** By popular demand

```
$ ls -al /forcecheck
ls: Zugriff auf '/forcecheck' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
$ grep -i sda1 ~/.profile
$ grep -i sda1 ~/.bash*
$ df | grep -v loop
Dateisystem    1K-Blöcke  Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev              989536        0    989536    0% /dev
tmpfs             204132     2960    201172    2% /run
/dev/sda1       13141092 11094244   1356372   90% /
/dev/sdb2       16376192 11428372   4109300   74% /usr
tmpfs            1020656        0   1020656    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120    0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1020656        0   1020656    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        4134900   782804   3142048   20% /home
/dev/sda6        5002076   168852   4577396    4% /var/www
/dev/sdd1      134043944 26464584 101061928   21% /var/www/vhost/[redacted]
tmpfs             204128        0    204128    0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: In `terminal` type `ls -al /forcecheck` and `grep -i sda1 ~/.profile` and `grep -i sda1 ~/.bash*`.

Comment: Also show me `df | grep -v loop`

Comment: Check the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sda` . Perhaps `/dev/sda1` is very damaged. How did it get that way?